# How to store complete edit history OSM PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, openstreetmap, ubuntu

I successfully built a PostgreSQL server on an Ubuntu VM and populated it with the latest Geofabrik .osm.pbf complete dataset for Nepal.  Now, I'd like to append to that dataset all of the historic edit data.  I'd like to keep every version of every node, rel, and way, not just the latest, most up-to-date version.

My understanding is that `OSM2PGSQL` removes deprecated data when it appends the new data from a diff.  Is this correct?  If so, how can I go about storing a full history of edits, and not just the most recent ones?

When I try building an initial database with a full-history file like those found [here](http://osm.personalwerk.de/full-history-extracts/latest/asia/), I get a crash with a duplicate key error, both on macOS and on Ubuntu.

> Processing: Node(2760k 32.1k/s) Way(0k 0.00k/s) Relation(0
>   0.00/s)COPY_END for COPY planet_osm_ways FROM STDIN;  failed: ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "planet_osm_ways_pkey"
>   DETAIL:  Key (id)=(4748383) already exists. CONTEXT:  COPY
>   planet_osm_ways, line 2
>
> Error occurred, cleaning up

I tried following the OSM-history tutorial found [here](https://github.com/MaZderMind/osm-history-renderer/blob/master/TUTORIAL.md), but the dependencies used are deprecated on the latest Ubuntu and 1) make it so you have to uninstall curl (!!) and 2) meant I would have to dig into some dependency stuff which is way about my pay grade in terms of my experience with Ubuntu.

**To be clear**, I just want to store the date stamp and author of every previous edit to any existing node, relation, or way.  I don't care what the actual edit was, I don't need to see it on a map.  I just want to know *when it happened* and *who did it*.

Comment: So, summing up, all you need is a database with object type/id, version number, userid/username and timestamp. Why do you work with `osm2pgsql` then? That's a tool which is primarily used to prepare databases for _rendering_ purposes. I would recommend to write a small C++ program based on libosmium instead, extract only relevant details and directly insert the data in a database table(s). I don't remember seeing a readymade solution for it, i.e. you're on your own.

Comment: You're right on both fronts.  It was a bad approach.

Comment: See my answer, sorry if it's lacking in detail but there are >100 lines of code written today involved in the steps outlined so I think it's better to just explain the overarching structure of what I did.  Also per your comment, C or C++ would have been better than what I did, because Perl is such a memory hog I ended up losing a bunch of time over splitting my file into smaller files.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I ended up doing:

1. I turned my OSH file into XML
2. I wrote a Perl script to translate the resulting XML into JSON
3. I wrote a BASH script to take the XML file (>200MB) and cut it into a bunch of smaller ones with correct nested formatting, etc.
4. I used by Bash script to cut my XML into a ton of very small files.
5. I parsed each smaller file with my Perl script into JSON.
6. I haven't done it yet, but I will next populate a PostgreSQL database with those JSON files.  Since they are keyed to "id:datestamp", I know I won't get any duplicate key errors, so everything should work fine.

UPDATE:
My code worked, but it was unbelievably slow to parse XML in Perl. I am instead working on a solution in either Python or Ruby to parse pure PBF.